# Troubles when reading clearance source code

Tags: ruby, private, inject, clearance

```
def initialize_sign_in_guard_stack
  default_guard = DefaultSignInGuard.new(self)    
  guards = Clearance.configuration.sign_in_guards 

  guards.inject(default_guard) do |stack, guard_class|
    guard_class.new(self, stack)         
  end
end

class DefaultSignInGuard < SignInGuard
  def call
    if session.signed_in?
      success
    else
      failure default_failure_message.html_safe
    end
 end
end

class SignInGuard
  def initialize(session, stack = [])
    @session = session
    @stack = stack
  end
private
attr_reader :stack, :session

def signed_in?
  session.signed_in?
end

def current_user
  session.current_user
end
end

Pry(main)> Clearance.configuration.sign_in_guards # => []
```

No. 1

Since guards is an empty array, so what the `guard_class` refers to?
And how could it run the new method? Can you explain what does this line of code do?

No. 2

`signed_in`? is a private method of `SignInGuard`. I know that only '`self`' can 
call it. Here, `session.signed_in`? Why does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No1: To nothing. The block will never execute when you call it on an empty array, therefore a value will not be assigned. It is like asking what is `item` in `[].each { |item| puts item }`. The idea is when it is not empty to create objects of a list of guard classes. Then `guard_class` will refer to each individual guard class.

No2: You can't call private methods with explicit receiver, even if it is `self`. However, here `signed_in?` called on `session` is `Session#signed_in?`, not `SignInGuard#signed_in?`, which is public so it is fine.

Comment: To clarify a bit further, we pass the `default_guard` as a parameter `inject` so you'll always end up with *at least* the default guard after `initialize_sign_in_guard_stack`